# How can we do "polls" in "chat"?

Tags: discussion, chat

Moderation decided to close and delete my question [Winter Bash … does it matter to you this year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339617/winter-bash-does-it-matter-to-you-this-year) I asked today.

In the explanation about that close/deletion, a moderator also mentioned:

> Chat is a better venue to poll people's feelings on winter bash participation, if you have to.

Okay. But how is that supposed to work?

A question can be voted on, up and down. Answers can be given directly to the question, and can be voted on, too.

Chats only allow unstructured communication, and the "reach" of people to participate ... is just that subset of community members that happens to be in that chat room around that time. And of course, people can only upvote other comments.

Thus: I really don't see how chat "polls" could result in anything else but a random glance of a random people.

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Uh...maybe first ask what you actually *need* an exact and exhaustive poll for. It seems the close-reason's very *essence* is hinged on the fact that the subjective gossip among random people gained from an informal chat session is better suited for this question.

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica The point is: In many situations, I found it very helpful to understand "where the community sees itself", because that enables individual community members to position themselves in that context. When respected members of the community outline their position with reasonable arguments, that enables others to follow. In other words: a **lot** of the content here is that kind of "laying out options", to then hear opinions about those options.

Comment: seems they felt your question wasn't going to attract positive reactions, and therefore needed to be silenced.

Comment: So... is the question coming back?

Comment: No. It will not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That is an utterly inappropriate deletion. Meta is *the place* to gauge community feeling about things that will or could potentially take place on Stack Exchange sites.

**You don't do polls in chat. That's annoying.**

If you're a regular in a chat room, you can certainly ask the other participants what they think, but that's not a poll so much as…well, chatting. However, if you're not a regular in chat, you should not just go into a chat room and start trying to poll everyone. That's almost guaranteed to get you kicked from chat.

You *could*, I suppose, start a new chat room with the express purpose of running a poll, but I don't expect that will end very well, given the difficulty of publicizing your chat room. As soon as you start attempting to publicize it, you'll be annoying folks and breaking all sorts of rules. And if you can't adequately publicize it, your poll will be useless.

So, this is why we host these questions on Meta. Yes, it abuses the Stack Exchange platform for "discussion", which it was never designed to do. But Meta has been doing that since its inception, and it turns out that the platform is adaptable and flexible enough to be abused in this way.

Votes (both up and down) are an *excellent* proxy for gauging community consensus. As a bonus, this system is fair, efficient, and low-noise: everyone gets one vote, and there is no need to post a noisy comment. If you do have something substantive and constructive to say, then you can post an answer, which can then, in turn, be voted upon by the community.

We do this on Meta Stack Overflow all the time, and have literally done it since the creation of the Meta site. It's also regularly done on Meta Stack Exchange. (Which, for years, was identical to Meta Stack Overflow.)

The moderator who deleted that question made the wrong decision, couched in some kind of inscrutable logic about "pits of despair". Asking people whether or not they want hats is not a "pit of despair". If a question happens to attract inappropriate comments or responses, then those responses should be dealt with. However, there was nothing whatsoever inherently wrong with either the question or its presentation.

With specific regard to Winter Bash, the question you asked is well supported by precedent. Stack Exchange staff members have, on multiple occasions, posted questions on Meta sites with the express intent of gauging whether or not the community was interested in participating in Winter Bash for the upcoming year. There have also been a variety of polls and other pseudo-questions designed to solicit feedback regarding Winter Bash, also created by staff members. (Many of these questions are *now* closed, but that's because their topic of discussion is obsolete, not because the question's style is inappropriate on Meta.)

**Update:** Poll-style questions about Winter Bash seem to be [once again permitted this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340171/show-off-your-hats-2019-edition) (and that's just one of many examples). That's pretty good evidence that there's been no policy change regarding Winter Bash polls/discussions on Meta Stack Exchange. So, unless that question and its brethren get closed and deleted by the Stack Exchange moderators, I think it's *very* clear that the moderation of the question under discussion here was a targeted decision based on something altogether different than what their public statements are suggesting.

Comment: Thank you for articulating this so well. I can understand maybe closing the question if it needed to be made less inflammatory or something, but the deletion seemed beyond the pale. I also like how I was directed to go look at the deleted post that I can’t see if I wanted to understand the reasoning behind the deletion.

Comment: And yet - this basically tells us to ignore "don't ask" cause people demand we do. Mods need a certain freedom to act without pressure from both sides. Not really happening.

Comment: @Journeyman Note that the "don't ask" guidance is *identical* on Meta as it is on main sites, which are its intended target. It doesn't necessarily apply to Meta, which, as you well know, is a whole different world on a number of levels. I absolutely agree that moderators need a certain freedom to act, exercising their best judgment. This answer is, however, conveying that I disagree with the judgment that led to this decision, which is also an important function of the community with respect to moderation (checks and balances, accountability, etc.).

Comment: And to a large extent - well, it feels like folks are trying to almost constantly mob us on every decision. I'm fine with the consultative aspect of moderation but at some point, we actually need to make these decisions without being paralysed by every decision having a monumental pile on. The rules are there. We're enforcing them as we feel is beneficial to the community. We're having to adapt to a community that seems at odds with us, and each other and using the tools, and rules at our disposal to do it.

Comment: I'm not at odds with any specific moderators, or even the moderator team as a whole. I'm at odds with this particular decision, because it violates long-standing precedent, is entirely lacking justification, and I do not feel it is in the best interest of the community. Dismissing disagreement as a "pile on" is an annoying cop-out. That's not what's happening here. I expressed disagreement with a specific moderator decision, and several other members of the community appear to agree with me. That is…how it goes. I feel strongly that your decision is wrong. It is unrelated to other events. @jou

Comment: I can't help but wonder if this fragmentation of the community ("Use the Tavern", "Use the Loop", etc...) is deliberate or not. I feel like Meta is pushed into obsolescence.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I’m sorry that y’all are in the position you’re in, and I understand quite well that sometimes what the most vocal part of the community wants is not good for the site, but deleting content that is off-topic but not otherwise violating any rules is not a good way to proceed. It makes it look like mods who are getting a little worn down are removing stuff they personally don’t like instead of following the rules. The current situation sucks. Sanitizing content isn’t going to help it get better, it’s just going to cause more negative feelings and bad will.

Comment: And yet it's something that we did before this, and do on every other site. The massive comment threads are not normal. People  who would rather assume bad intent than realize we still have many of the same rules will do so anyway.

Comment: This is exactly my and Colleen's point. You brought up "massive comment threads", but nobody here was talking about comments at all. They're talking about the deletion of a question soliciting community feedback regarding Winter Bash. A deletion that is, contrary to your assertions, *utterly unprecedented*, considering we've had polls like this just about every year around Winter Bash on such topics as "do you want hats?", "what kind of hats do you want?", "which hats did you discover?", "any hats you didn't like?", etc. There has definitely been a shift in approach to moderation. @jou

Comment: Yes. Shifting so much that some think 50% of the stuff on MSE could or should be removed. https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8103137#8103137

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am not talking about comments. Deleting comments is an important part of what moderators do. I have have removed 17.4K of them on ELL over the years according to the dashboard, and I’m sure moderators on larger sites have rightfully removed more. I haven’t ever deleted a question with multiple answers as far as I can recall.

Answer (score 10):

A distinct self-answer, to outline a few thoughts that probably should have gone into the question itself, but I think it would be misleading future readers if I would put all that into the question hours later.

The word *polling* came up, and unfortunately, I jumped on that train...

Now, the German language has the word "Meinungsbildung", which resembles the often complicated process of shaping an opinion. I think that is what a large fraction of questions/answers on MSE are: a means that community members use to identify "option space", and then to determine where to position themselves, first as individuals, but also (via voting, and consensus) as a group.

That was the purpose of my now deleted question—to help positioning the community, now that Winter Bash 2019 is "officially" taking place.

The fact that this complex request is now reduced to "you should do polling in chats, or even outsource that discussion to some 3rd party site", well, that leaves me speechless.

And in that moment when the community is worried that SE Inc. will replace MSE/metas with "The Loop", the serious suggestion is "you could take your stuff (including discussions) to polleverywhere.com".

---

Besides: one objection to my question that was raised quickly was the *expectation* that my question would turn into "another pit of discontent", only attracting negativity, which didn't happen, in my eyes.

The question attracted clear, factual answers, no derogatory language, none of that. Even two rather positive answers that suggest that one can be relaxed about Winter Bash whilst still being aware of the ongoing "churn".

So, to be really clear about this: the only overly negative thing in regards to Winter Bash that happened today was the deletion of my question. The message that got sent to all people upvoting content there, and to the people who considered the question legitimate and worth answering was "You're not welcome".

History doesn't repeat, but it rhymes. A feeling very close to [finding out that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336398/285661) "pronoun FAQ v1" got deleted.

The one thing I learned for sure yesterday: me [defending](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338878/285661) controversial moderator decisions ... not going to happen any more, any time soon.

Comment: Rhymes do not match here. `pronoun FAQ v1` was deleted by a CM, your question was deleted by a consensus of the remaining moderators on this site. I agree your question should not have been deleted. But the two problems are different.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That is the point of a rhyme: similar, but not the same. From the perspective of those who see their content deleted in such ways, it just feels very similar. Also note: this is also about trust. The moderators here are appointed, not elected. Their authority can only be trust, as they don't have a election based mandate. My trust ... suffered quite a bit today.

Comment: It might surprise you but I do not think these are similar at all, if only because the decision to delete your question most probably did not go through a CM.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It doesn't surprise me, you already said so ;-) I can easily agree that we disagree here. What I am trying to say is: when the community loses the trust into the appointed MSE moderators, then there is *effectively* no more difference between a SE Inc. staffer CM coming in and doing something ... or a moderator doing something. Because the assumption is that all these people follow the wishes of the same master. And when you look around, you will find that more and more users here raise that fear. Which is really unfortunate, and extremely bad for the overall community.

Comment: I can understand that. From a social standpoint the remaining moderators here are the ones who have not resigned (or have resigned and went through the process to come back). It is easy to compound that with them being aligned with the current stance of the CMs and higher. Then again I do not believe that every CM is on the party line either. And from a technical standpoint, the moderator could have cast a binding close vote on your question, which is reversible, instead of a binding delete vote, which is not.

Comment: Where do you see “consensus”, @Frederic?

Comment: @Cody, in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339629/how-to-do-polls-in-chat/339650#comment1134232_339637) from TinkeringBell: `...you probably already know but moderators work in teams, so in no way was the decision unilateral.`

Comment: @Frederic ...I see. Having been a moderator myself, I find that a bit hard to believe. Every moderation decision I make is mine, and mine alone. Yes, moderators work as a team and generally follow the same standards, but that doesn’t imply that we moderate by committee. If we tried to do that, we’d never get anything done. The ideal is more that all moderators are interchangeable, rather than being a committee, although this isn’t truly achievable, either. And none of that excludes the possibility of mistakes or misjudgments. I speak from experience. :-)

Comment: @Cody, thank you for your enlightening comment. I have a few things to re-evaluate now, notably in regard to the *interchangeable* ideal you speak of.

Comment: @Frederic Understandable that that would give you pause. Would anyone really want *two* moderators like me? :-)

Comment: @CodyGray To be fair, our team would consult each other on occasion to make sure we weren’t overreacting to something or missing some of the pieces. It’s entirely possible that a team of 3 whose active times seems to overlap quite a bit could have talked it over and decided to delete it. That means that the moderators don’t trust the community to do the right thing any more and/or that they are going to bludgeon down anything that might possibly taint the upcoming festivities.

Comment: @Colleen Yes, that is possible, but it’s still hard to believe that moderators discuss closure and/or deletion of every question. Maybe this is colored by my experience on a site as large as SO, where discussing everything would lead to total paralysis. Mods do discuss with each other in cases where they’re uncertain, but I don’t see any evidence of uncertainty or doubt in the actions taken on that post. I share your concerns about the mod involved—and possibly the entire team, if the comment is to be taken at face value—is going to be actively suppressing anything that might be controversial.

Answer (score 4):

> Chats only allow unstructured communication, and the "reach" of people to participate ... is just that subset of community members that happens to be in that chat room around that time.

The great thing about a poll is that it doesn't require 'everyone' to respond. A political poll doesn't require the entire nation that hold the right to vote to respond, a poll on meta is off-topic and will only get you whoever happens to be around on meta, and a poll in chat gets you whoever is in chat.

You're making a misinterpretation (or misrepresentation) of my comment though: It says chat is a better place *to poll* feelings. To poll being a verb that means nothing more than to take a sampling of the attitudes or opinions of people.

You ask what people feel in rooms *you're a regular in*, and they respond. That's how you poll (verb, not noun) people's feelings about participating in Winter Bash in chat on SE.

Answer (score 4):

> How to do polls in “chat”?

While you wouldn't be able to use [OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/) (like Stack Exchange uses for elections), since you must supply every voter's email address ahead of time, you could use [SurveyMonkey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/online-polls/), [Fandom's](https://www.fandom.com/curse-privacy-policy) [Straw Poll](https://www.strawpoll.me/), [etc.](https://bloggerjet.com/17-best-online-survey-poll-apps-reviewed/), or any other [open-access poll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-access_poll).

Simply create your poll and post your link.

> I really don't see how chat "polls" could result in anything else but a random glance of random people.

If your poll is important and of general interest you can ask to have it pinned.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Albeit I guess the term poll itself  might be a problem here. I picked it up from the moderstor comment, but after thinking about it for a while, I find it misleading. I will update my question on that later maybe. The big difference I see: a poll comes with preset choices. And when every user leaves his own answers, then we just outsourced a potentially meaningful discussion from MSE.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica Yes, that wording is a bit confusing, seeing how a poll without discussion is often largely useless and even more so on such a subjective topic *and* in chat. But on the other hand, asking "how to host a discussion in chat" would be...kind of a no-brainer. ;-)

Comment: And fyi: your expectations that my earlier question would overly attract negativity, I didn't see that happening. Most answers were rather positive and well thought. I found the overall sentiment to be pretty welcoming towards winter bash 2019. For me, the only big negative thing was: the question and the positivity within the answers was all discarded and thrown out.

Comment: GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica [PollEverywhere](https://www.polleverywhere.com/support/articles/create-activities/open-ended) allows open-ended responses. Your question can be: "What do you think about ..." and people can respond with anything (not just for/against).

Comment: @Ghostcat: there's a difference between 'a poll' and 'to poll' (which I used) < The latter is a verb meaning nothing more than to take a sampling of the attitudes or opinions of people, and has nothing to do with preset choices. Though you even "offered" two preset choices in your "question".

Comment: As Chris already mentioned, let's hope that the question isn't asking "how to host a discussion in chat", [other advice would precede that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59995/282094).

Comment: also @Rob that link is confusing... are you sure you wanted to link to an answer by Jon Skeet on top issues with low quality questions?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell the link is for his link at the end of his question, and to scroll up to the question itself. That answer in and of itself is also relevant. With one upvote it wasn't confusing to everyone.

Comment: @Rob ah, thanks! I didn't click through the links yet. Will do :)