# What is the purpose of MSE in contrast to chat and defining community consensus?

Tags: support, chat, meta

This is what I *think* (or believe) how the MSE Q&A site and the various chat rooms "come together" as basis of our community:

- Within the various chat-rooms, depending on scope and audience, topics get thrown in, discussions happen (or not), feedback is given (or not), ... but in a very "volatile" way. (*1)
- Within the Q&A site, it is similar (with the intention to avoid overly lengthy discussions via comments), yet more "persistent".

What I would like to understand better: is community consensus only possible in the Q&A site? Or is just normal that 20, 50 people in a chat room agree on a specific subject, and that somehow turns into common knowledge, and an official position of the community?

Or can we say: to claim "the community is in support of this or that", that there always needs to be one (or more) post(s) on the Q&A site, with significant view and vote counts?(*2)

---

<sub>(*1): "Volatile": there are transcripts for the chat rooms, but in many team rooms, there is so much traffic that (imho) even important things can easily get lost. To understand "what affects the community", I am scanning through new MSE/MSO questions regularly, it seems burdensome to do that with chat rooms, too.</sub>

<sub>(*2): That makes more sense to me. And: really don't recall that people use links to chat room snippets regularly when putting up arguments about past "community decision X" from 5 years in the past.</sub>

I did scroll through plenty of pages with old questions tagged with chat, community, ... but I found only things like [Toward a philosophy of Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat) or [Make the Stack Overflow chat more prominently linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255993/make-the-stack-overflow-chat-more-prominently-linked) that mainly talk about how chats are organized, managed ... but not about their relation to "community opinion building".

Comment: Don't over think this. A chat room is just that, a room where users chat. Only a few rooms have a codified chapter and an RO team that keeps such rooms in check. Only an MSE post can and should be the source of understanding the community. Chat is maybe helping for formulating / wording the posts on MSE. By no means users should have to dig through a chat transcript to learn what consensus is.

Comment: @rene I thought so, too. Until yesterday, and meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339629/how-to-do-polls-in-chat and some folks going A) hey, why ask such things here when you could turn to a chat room or 3rd party polling service instead and (imho) worse: B) hey, "50% of the content on MSE should be thrown out" anyway. Yes, that made me think about the foundations of this place. Because I see people acting in different ways recently. Beyond that: feel free to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you've just brought up [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339629/369802) question of yours and the deleted question that one is about (which was asking "Winter Bash, does it matter to you?" and "What does the community feel?")...  Let me set a few things straight.

What people feel about Winter Bash mattering to them personally does not require community consensus. That's the kind of post where community consensus will never be reached because everyone will have their own feelings. It also does not have any actual problem that requires this community consensus.

*Community consensus* involves questions with [actual problems, where not every answer is equally valid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). It is about more than asking 'how people feel about something', or 'what does the community think about this'. A post looking for community consensus sets out a premise, an actual problem, something people would like to see fixed or changed but can't do on their own.

Community consensus concerns whether X is on-topic, whether tag Y should be burninated, or propose implementing feature Z. A quick search for ['community consensus'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=community+consensus) on MSE shows you already a lot of these types of questions.

So yes, in that sense, community consensus can't be reached in chat. You'd want a record of people setting out their views on whether something is a problem or not, and give reason why, and you want others to be able to engage with those arguments. You also want something you can link other users to when they complain about site policy and community consensus.

<sub>*Community consensus is also a strange word for Meta SE, as this site concerns network-wide events too, and is essentially at the same time it's own meta. A community consensus on MSE about a feature request does not automatically mean all child sites will have the same community consensus*</sub>

Comment: I appreciate the clarifications. Beyond that, I didn't mention my other questions here on purpose. I am asking in the *general* sense, not about my specific case. Sure, what happened there got me thinking, but as said: I did try to research if/what was previously stated here about this topic. Couldn't find meaningful content, thus asking seems a natural step here.

Comment: @GhostCat Your questions make an example of what caused this specific confusion over what community consensus was or where it was reached, so I've used them. They're also clear enough that I think other users will understand them too, so in that sense... Thank you, I guess!

Comment: In that sense ... you are welcome. As said, I appreciate your input here.